# Grails duplicate form submissions and fields validation

Tags: forms, validation, grails, form-submit

In controller I validate form input like this:

```
withForm {
    def user = new User(params)    
    if(user.save()) {
        render "success"
    } else {
        render view: "userForm", model: [user: user]
    }
}.invalidToken {
    render view: "userForm"
}
```

In form I add class error to the input field if there is some error on that field:

```
<input value="${user?.name}" name="name" type="text" class="text${user?.errors?.getFieldError("name") ? ' error':''}" id="name">
```

**Problem**:
Bean user is not seen in the view. It works ok if I remove withForm wrap.

Anyone has an idea what might be going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your form declaration include useToken, for example

```
<g:form useToken="true" ...>
```

Per the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.2/ref/Controllers/withForm.html), `withForm`

> The withForm method requires the use of the useToken attribute in a
>   form

**UPDATE**
Do you want the User bean returned on duplicate submission? you only return a User on unsuccessful save. If you want User return on duplicate submission try,

```
}.invalidToken {
  render view: "userForm", model: [user: user]
}
```

Comment: Yes it does use useToken tag.

Comment: do you want User bean returned on duplicate submission? you only return a User on unsuccessful save.

Comment: No, I want it returned when validation fails (that's in the else clause: render view: "userForm", model: [user: user]). It works ok if I omit withForm closure.

Comment: what does the rest of your controller action look like, I'm assuming that's only a snippet. Since render doesn't explicitly exit the controller action, the only thing I can think of is if you have additional code after withForm that may be interfering.

Comment: Yes it is a snippet. In actual controller I use return statements instead of renders and let the grails convention render appropriate view.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your view to display validation errors, your controller action needs to create a user instance and validate it. Your current `.invalidToken` block doesn't do this. A nice way to do this easily is have your controller action automatically create a `User` instance from your params:

```
def myAction(User user) {
    withForm { 
        if(user.save()) {
            render "success"
        } else {
            render view: "userForm", model: [user: user]
        }
    }.invalidToken {
        render view: "userForm", model: [user: user]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for automatic creation of a User instance tip. However, I don't want to display errors when token is invalid, just when token is valid but validation fails. I think my upper code is ok for this purpose.